# The X's and O's aren't showing up when running my tic tac toe JavaScript game. How do I fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I have been following a couple tutorials online for the tic tac toe project but with both times that I have attempted, I have gotten the same error where the X's and O's aren't showing but the other features are. I have my HTML, CSS and JavaScript code below. I apologise if it isn't the best, I am a beginner.

```js
const playerTurn = document.querySelector('.turn');

let gameActive = true;
let currentPlayer = "X";
let gameArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

const winMessage = () => `Player ${currentPlayer} wins!`;
const drawMessage = () => `It's a Draw!`;
const currentPlayerTurn = () => `Player ${currentPlayer}'s Turn`;

playerTurn.innerHTML = currentPlayerTurn();

function handleCellPlayed() {
  gameArray[clickedCellIndex] = currentPlayer;
  clickedCell.innerHTML = currentPlayer;
}

function handlePlayerChange() {
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
  gameArray.innerHTML = currentPlayerTurn();
}
const winningConditions = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

function handleResultValidation() {
  let roundWon = false;
  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    const winCondition = winningConditions[i];
    let a = gameArray[winCondition[0]];
    let b = gameArray[winCondition[1]];
    let c = gameArray[winCondition[2]];
    if (a === '' || b === '' || c === '') {
      continue;
    }
    if (a === b && b === c) {
      roundWon = true;
      break
    }
  }
  if (roundWon) {
    playerTurn.innerHTML = winMessage();
    gameActive = false;
    return;
  }
  let roundDraw = !gameArray.includes("");
  if (roundDraw) {
    playerTurn.innerHTML = drawMessage();
    gameActive = false;
    return;
  }
  handlePlayerChange();
}

function handleCellClick() {
  const clickedCell = clickedCellEvent.target;
  const clickedCellIndex = parseInt(
    clickedCell.getAttribute('data-cell-index')
  );
  if (gameArray[clickedCellIndex] !== "" || !gameActive) {
    return;
  }
  handleCellPlayed(clickedCell, clickedCellIndex);
  handleResultValidation();
}

function handleRestartGame() {
  gameActive = true;
  currentPlayer = "X";
  gameArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  playerTurn.innerHTML = currentPlayerTurn();
  document.querySelectorAll('.cell')
    .forEach(cell => cell.innerHTML = "");
}

document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', handleCellClick));
document.querySelector('.restart').addEventListener('click', handleRestartGame);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.game {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  width: 304px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.cell {
  font-family: "Permanent Marker", cursive;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #333333;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<div class="game">
  <div data-cell-index="0" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="1" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="2" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="3" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="4" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="5" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="6" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="7" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="8" class="cell"></div>
</div>
<h2 class="turn"></h2>
<button class="restart">Restart</button>
```

I have managed to get the restart button to show after a couple of changes to my JavaScript code.

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: clickedCellEvent is not defined"`

Answer (score 0):

Your function `handleCellPlayed` does not take any arguments, so it does not get the `clickedCell` or the `clickedCellIndex` that you try to pass it.

Try changing it to

```
function handleCellPlayed(clickedCell, clickedCellIndex) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few details. `handleCellPlayed()` needs to receive the parameters and
to get the data from `data-yourvalue`, you can use `dataset.yourvalue`.

Here a working example:

```js
const playerTurn = document.querySelector('.turn');

let gameActive = true;
let currentPlayer = "X";
let gameArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

const winMessage = () => `Player ${currentPlayer} wins!`;
const drawMessage = () => `It's a Draw!`;
const currentPlayerTurn = () => `Player ${currentPlayer}'s Turn`;

playerTurn.innerHTML = currentPlayerTurn();

function handleCellPlayed(clickedCell, clickedCellIndex) {
  gameArray[clickedCellIndex] = currentPlayer;
  clickedCell.innerHTML = currentPlayer;
}

function handlePlayerChange() {
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
  gameArray.innerHTML = currentPlayerTurn();
}
const winningConditions = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

function handleResultValidation() {
  let roundWon = false;
  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    const winCondition = winningConditions[i];
    let a = gameArray[winCondition[0]];
    let b = gameArray[winCondition[1]];
    let c = gameArray[winCondition[2]];
    if (a === '' || b === '' || c === '') {
      continue;
    }
    if (a === b && b === c) {
      roundWon = true;
      break
    }
  }
  if (roundWon) {
    playerTurn.innerHTML = winMessage();
    gameActive = false;
    return;
  }
  let roundDraw = !gameArray.includes("");
  if (roundDraw) {
    playerTurn.innerHTML = drawMessage();
    gameActive = false;
    return;
  }
  handlePlayerChange();
}

function handleCellClick(e) {
  const clickedCell = e.target;
  const cellIndex = e.target.dataset.cellIndex;
  const clickedCellIndex = parseInt(cellIndex);
  
  if (gameArray[clickedCellIndex] !== "" || !gameActive) {
    return;
  }
  handleCellPlayed(clickedCell, clickedCellIndex);
  handleResultValidation();
}

function handleRestartGame() {
  gameActive = true;
  currentPlayer = "X";
  gameArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  playerTurn.innerHTML = currentPlayerTurn();
  document.querySelectorAll('.cell')
    .forEach(cell => cell.innerHTML = "");
}

document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', handleCellClick));
document.querySelector('.restart').addEventListener('click', handleRestartGame);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.game {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  width: 304px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.cell {
  font-family: "Permanent Marker", cursive;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #333333;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<div class="game">
  <div data-cell-index="0" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="1" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="2" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="3" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="4" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="5" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="6" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="7" class="cell"></div>
  <div data-cell-index="8" class="cell"></div>
</div>
<h2 class="turn"></h2>
<button class="restart">Restart</button>
```